# What is the name of a Smart Contract?

Tags: openethereum

I'm new to Ethereum technology and I'm trying to find the definition for the name of a Smart Contract but I can't find anything useful. What is really the meaning of the name of the Smart Contract? Is this unique or different Smart Contract with different hashes can have the same name? Is it required, when do you need to assign a name to your Smart Contract and when not?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of a smart contract is not actually a required field, but it is often included as a way to give the contract a human-readable identity.

The name of a contract can be any string value that you choose, but it's important to note that contract names are not unique in the same way that contract addresses are. Two different contracts can have the same name, but they will have different addresses.

In Solidity, the name of a contract is declared using the contract keyword, followed by the name of the contract. For example:

```
contract MyContract {
    // Contract code goes here
}
```

The name of the contract is used to identify the contract in Solidity code and in external applications that interact with the contract. In some cases, you may want to assign a name to your contract to make it easier to identify and interact with.

For example, if you are creating a token contract, you may want to assign a name to your contract that reflects the name of the token. This can make it easier for users to identify your token when they are interacting with it.

However, in other cases, you may not need to assign a name to your contract. For example, if you are creating a contract that performs a specific function, such as managing a voting system or a supply chain, you may not need to assign a name to the contract as long as it has a clear and descriptive purpose.

Overall, the name of a smart contract is not a required field, but it can be a helpful way to give your contract a human-readable identity and make it easier to identify and interact with. However, it's important to note that contract names are not unique in the same way that contract addresses are.

Answer (score 0):

The contract name is just an identifier. Helps differentiate between contracts in your work environment, but it has no rules to it in the sense that 2 smart contract with different contents can have the same name on chain, there is not limitation to that, you can even deploy a contract twice and it will be deployed in different addresses even with the same contents and same ABI.

It just makes it easier to call a smart contract using a tool like ethers to call them by the name with methods such as `getContractFactory`  and `getContractAt` .